# WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting RngReadAndSkip cause there is no registered converter for this op

Tags: while-loop, converters

WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting RngReadAndSkip cause there is no registered converter for this op
WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting Bitcast cause there is no registered converter for this op.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting Bitcast cause there is no registered converter for this op.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting StatelessRandomUniformV2 cause there is no registered converter for this op.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting ImageProjectiveTransformV3 cause there is no registered converter for this op.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting RngReadAndSkip cause there is no registered converter for this op.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting Bitcast cause there is no registered converter for this op.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting Bitcast cause there is no registered converter for this op.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting StatelessRandomUniformV2 cause there is no registered converter for this op.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting ImageProjectiveTransformV3 cause there is no registered converter for this op.

I am getting this error while building a model please solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe due to versioning of tensorflow?  I am now getting this error because I installed the version that uses GPU

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).